# Dataiku : Job failed: Error in Python process: At line 158: <class 'NameError'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataiku

I work on Dataiku and I have a jupyter notebook which is work and now I want to include this on python recipe. The objective is to write dataframe pandas in a dataset.

`data_f` is the name of my dataframe and `output_gen_python` is the name of my dataset in dataiku.

I have this error :

> Job failed: Error in Python process: At line 158: <class 'NameError'>: name 'data_df' is not defined

Here is my code :

```
import dataiku
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from dataiku import pandasutils as pdu
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Read recipe inputs
batches_types_copy = dataiku.Dataset("batches_types_copy")
batches_types_copy_df = batches_types_copy.get_dataframe()
Last_hour_extract = dataiku.Dataset("Last_hour_extract")
last_hour_extract_df = Last_hour_extract.get_dataframe()


class OutputMode(object):
    ...
            
class IDCalculation_I:
    def _preGenerateID(self,outputMode,data_df):
        ...
    
    def generateID(self,outputMode,data_df):
        pass
        
class IDCase1(IDCalculation_I):
    def generateID(self,outputMode,data_df):
        ...
        return data_df
                        
class IDCase2(IDCalculation_I): 
    def generateID(self,outputMode,data_df):
        ...
        return data_df
                    
class Fingerprinter(object):
    def __init__(self,outputMode):
        self._outputMode = outputMode
    
    def _generateID(self,data_df):
        return self._outputMode.getCaseID().generateID(self._outputMode,data_df)
        
    def run(self,data_df):
        # GenerateID
        data_df = self._generateID(data_df)
        return data_df
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._outputMode)
    
    
outputMode = OutputMode('EEA','06:00:00','08:00:00',pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'),CONST_MODE_CONT,IDCase1())
fp_calculator = Fingerprinter(outputMode)

output_gen_python_df = data_df # Compute a Pandas dataframe to write into output_gen_python

# Write recipe outputs
output_gen_python = dataiku.Dataset("output_gen_python")
output_gen_python.write_with_schema(output_gen_python_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, on line 52 you are attempting to assign `output_gen_python_df` to `data_df`.

**How to fix it?**

Since you've initiated the variable `fp_calculator` with your `Fingerprinter` class in it the way you fix your error is:

`data_df = fp_calculator.run()`

which will return your dataframe